# Create action in controller to create an appointment between users and doctors - 204 NO RESPONSE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I'm building an API for an app where a user can make appointments with a doctor.

Everything is working just fine but it's returning ***204 - No content*** when I try to post a new appointment in Postman.

My schema:

```
create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.time "time"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "doctor_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["doctor_id"], name: "index_appointments_on_doctor_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_appointments_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "doctors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "speciality"
    t.integer "years_of_experience"
    t.integer "likes"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "appointments", "doctors"
  add_foreign_key "appointments", "users"
end
```

My appointments controller:

```
class Api::V1::AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentUserConcern

  def index
    @appointments = Appointment.all
    render json: @appointments
  end

  def create
    if @current_user
      @appointment = @current_user.appointments.build(appointment_params)
      if @appointment.save
        render json: @appointment 
      else
        render json: { status: 401 }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def appointment_params
      params.require(:appointment).permit(:time, :date, @current_user.id, :doctor_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: In appointment_params I tried to change @current_user.id to user_id and got the same answer

Comment: Are there any clues in your rails console log ?. Can you provide those logs ?. Look for some halted actions due to some before action, or check if there are any redirects. In case you can provide the logs, please include all the request starting from the controller being executed, including the params and everything else including the render parts as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's not need of sending `@current_user.id` in appointment_params as user_id will be assigned automatically when this line `@appointment = @current_user.appointments.build(appointment_params)` execute.

Coming to your issue make sure you are sending a POST request and "body" data in the correct JSON format from PostMan. As per your method `appointment_params` the request body should look like this

```
{
   appointment: {
      time: "",
      date: "",
      doctor_id: 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Now I'm getting:

Processing by Api::V1::AppointmentsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"appointment"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "doctor_id"=>"4", "date"=>"2020-02-20", "time"=>"19:30"}}
No template found for Api::V1::AppointmentsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

I don't know why is looking for a template as other post methods are working

Comment: Can you verify is your code executing `if` block inside `create` action or not? Because your are not handling what would happen if `@current_user` is nil. This could be the reason why you are getting no content, as you are not rendering any thing in this case